# How to store international characters in XML?

Tags: xml

I've a problem whereby the XML that I've generated contains:

```
<attribute name="Actors">Trevante Rhodes , AndrÃ© Holland , Janelle MonÃ¡e</attribute>
```

but it should be this:

```
<attribute name="Actors">Trevante Rhodes , André Holland , Janelle Monáe</attribute>
```

[@IntelliData's answer to the question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421647/xmlparser-has-problems-reading-utf8-characters/41430903#41430903) seems to suggest that the only solution is to replace them with their HTML encoded counter parts.

So... if I have a source file that may contain any foreign character from one or more countries, does this mean that I'd have to write a routine to do just that?

And if I have no choice, is there a more efficient way to do this search and replace?

```
myData = myData.Replace("À","&#192;").Replace("à","&#224;").Replace(...)
```

**MORE INFO**

To create the XML file, I am using

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myTxtFile))
{
...
}
```

myTxtFile thus contains

```
 Trevante Rhodes , André Holland , Janelle Monáe , Ashton...
```

I then open the .txt file using:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mySourceFile, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
...
some processing to assign the data to XML nodes...
...
}
```

and finally create the XML file:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(xmlDataFilename, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))) 
{
...
myXMLObject.outerXml
...
}
```

which produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<productRequest>
    <attribute name="Actors"> Trevante Rhodes , AndrÃ© Holland , Janelle MonÃ¡e , Ashton...</attribute>
</productRequest>
```

**MORE INFO 2**

The answer to the search and replace question lies
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321331/replace-multiple-string-elements-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What encoding doe your xml specifiy? What encoding is it actually? What are you using to view the xml?

Comment: The XML has this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> and to view the XML, I used Firefox.

Comment: Well, it seems Firefox does not honor the specified xml-encoding  since from the look of it the special characters are actually encoded as UTF-8. Does the receiving application have any problems with the UTF-8 encoded special characters? If not then it is essentially a problem of your debugging tools (i.e. Firefox)...

Comment: Open the XML file in visual studio. Does it still exhibit odd encoding? If not, that's just FF.  If for some reason you have to support viewing xml documents in a web browser, then you'll need to encode the document for viewing, but not for storage in a file.

Comment: Good points, both.  Will check.  But why was I marked down for asking a reasonable question?  Before I posted, I did do some research, and it's a problem that is genuinely stumping me.